# URL rewrite with external JSON query

Tags: plugins, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules, json

I wrote a plugin that can fetch data from an external JSON source and displays a very few details in a list. Each item is clickable to be displayed with more details on a specific template. To do this, each item has its own URL like this :
http://localhost/details/?id=125

The get parameter is meant to retrieve more data from the JSON source thanks to query_vars. It works without a hitch but I would like URLs to be rewrote this way :
http://localhost/details/name-of-the-item/id

Is that possible ? How can I do this ? (I can pass as many get parameters as possible from the list page if needed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try URL rewriting like that

```
add_action("wp_loaded", function () {


    add_rewrite_tag("%id%", "([^&]+)");

    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^details/[^&]+/([0-9]+)/?',
        'index.php?id=$matches[1]&pagename=details',
        'top'
    );


});
```

And then flush rewrite rules cache one time in Settings -> Permalinks.

With this rewriting, the identifier is no more in `$_GET` but you can get it with https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var.

Comment: It would be better to use `get_query_var()`, rather than accessing the global directory.

Comment: thank you @JacobPeattie I was searching for the function "get_query_vars" and because I don't found it, I though there is no other solution than global var.